# Convert PostgreSQL age function output to upper case

Tags: postgresql, datetime, string-function

I am working with **PostgreSQL 8.4.4**. I am calculating time difference between two Unix time-stamps using PostgreSQL's `age` function. I am getting the output as expected. The only thing I want is to convert the time difference in UPPERCASE.
For example,

```
select coalesce(nullif(age(to_timestamp(1389078075), to_timestamp(1380703432))::text,''), UPPER('Missing')) FROM transactions_transactions WHERE id = 947
```

This query giving the result as

> 3 mons 4 days 22:17:23

But I want this output to be like

> 3 MONTHS 4 DAYS 22:17:23

**Note**: I am using this for dynamic report generation purpose. So I cannot convert it to UPPERCASE after fetching from database. I want it to be in UPPERCASE at the time of coming from database itself, i.e., in the query.

Comment: Postgres 8.4. is outdated and not maintained or supported any more. You should _really_ upgrade to a recent version (e.g. 9.4)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @a_horse_with_no_name. We are going for up-gradation soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL's [`upper()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) function should be use

```
SELECT upper(age(to_timestamp(1389078075), to_timestamp(1380703432))::text) 
FROM transactions_transactions WHERE id = 947
```

as per OP's comment and edit

```
select upper(coalesce(nullif(age(to_timestamp(1389078075), to_timestamp(1380703432))::text,''), UPPER('Missing')))
```

Comment: when I use `upper` function with `coalesce` and `nullif` it is giving error: function upper(interval) does not exist

Comment: @Suyog You must give full information in the question,You did not mentioned it in the first time.

Comment: Thank you @winged panther, its working and I apologize for the insufficient information.